# Remove gap between areas of image

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, crop

I have merged two lung images using an online merging tool to display a full image.

[image]

The problem is that since the background of each image is black I got an unwanted gap between the lungs in the image displayed.

I would like to know if there is a way to remove an area from an image either with code with an algorithm  or with an online tool and reduce the gap between the lungs.

Another approach I checked was using OpenCV with Python for a panoramic image stitching, which I will try as a last resort to connect my images.

My desired result:

[image]

Comment: Get the contours of each lung. Then crop the bounding boxes. Then hconcat() the two images with a small black image between them. See https://note.nkmk.me/en/python-opencv-hconcat-vconcat-np-tile/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The Concept**:

1. Using the [`cv2.findContours()`](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d3/dc0/group__imgproc__shape.html#gadf1ad6a0b82947fa1fe3c3d497f260e0) method, we will get an array of all the contours detected in the image specified. Normally, we would preprocess the image *(for example, with the [`cv2.Canny()`](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/dd/d1a/group__imgproc__feature.html#ga04723e007ed888ddf11d9ba04e2232de) method)* before passing it into the `cv2.findContours()` method, but as the image we have now is a simple binary image with two very obvious blobs in it, it wouldn't be necessary.
2. We use the [`cv2.boundingBox()`](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d3/dc0/group__imgproc__shape.html#ga103fcbda2f540f3ef1c042d6a9b35ac7) method to find the `x, y, w, h` of each contour so that we can slice that part from the image.
3. We use the `x, y, w, h` detected to get two slices of the image, apply a border to each slice using the [`cv2.copyMakeBorder()`](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d2/de8/group__core__array.html#ga2ac1049c2c3dd25c2b41bffe17658a36) , and concatenate them together with the [`np.hstack()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.hstack.html) method.

**The Code**:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread("lungs.png")

img_gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
contours, _ = cv2.findContours(img_gray, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)

(x1, y1, w1, h1), (x2, y2, w2, h2) = sorted(map(cv2.boundingRect, contours))

lung_1 = cv2.copyMakeBorder(img[y1: y1 + h2, x1: x1 + w1], 20, 20, 20, 20, cv2.BORDER_CONSTANT)
lung_2 = cv2.copyMakeBorder(img[y2: y2 + h2, x2: x2 + w2], 20, 20, 20, 20, cv2.BORDER_CONSTANT)

cv2.imshow("result", np.hstack((lung_1, lung_2)))
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

**The Output**:

[image]

*Notes*:

1. At the line:

```
lung_1 = cv2.copyMakeBorder(img[y1: y1 + h2, x1: x1 + w1], 20, 20, 20, 20, cv2.BORDER_CONSTANT)
```

notice that we used `h2` instead of `h1`, as if we were to use the `h1` we defined, the `np.hstack()` method would throw an error due to the different heights of the arrays.

2. The `sorted()` at

```
(x1, y1, w1, h1), (x2, y2, w2, h2) = sorted(map(cv2.boundingRect, contours))
```

is to sort the `x, y, w, h` by their `x` property, so that the lungs are concatenated from left to right.

Answer (score 3):

Here is one way as mention in my comments for Python/OpenCV.

- Read input and convert to grayscale
- Threshold to binary
- Get external contours
- Filter contours to keep only large ones and put bounding box values into list. Also compute the max width and max height from bounding boxes.
- Set desired amount of padding
- Create a black image the size of max width and max height
- Sort the bounding box list by x value
- Get the first item from the list and crop and pad it
- Create a black image the size of max height and desired pad
- Horizontally concatenate with previous padded crop
- Get the second item from the list and crop and pad it
- Horizontally concatenate with previous padded result
- Pad all around as desired
- Save the output

Input:

[image]

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# load image
img = cv2.imread("lungs_mask.png", cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)

# threshold
thresh = cv2.threshold(img, 128, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]

# get the largest contour
contours = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
contours = contours[0] if len(contours) == 2 else contours[1]

# get bounding boxes of each contour if area large and put into list
cntr_list=[]
max_ht = 0
max_wd = 0
for cntr in contours:
    area = cv2.contourArea(cntr)
    if area > 10000:
        x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(cntr)
        cntr_list.append([x,y,w,h])
        if h > max_ht:
            max_ht = h
        if w > max_wd:
            max_wd = w
            
# set padded
padding = 25

# create black image of size max_wd,max_ht
black = np.zeros((max_ht,max_wd), dtype=np.uint8)

# sort contours by x value
def takeFirst(elem):
    return elem[0]
cntr_list.sort(key=takeFirst)

# Take first entry in sorted list and crop and pad
item = cntr_list[0]
x = item[0]
y = item[1]
w = item[2]
h = item[3]
crop = thresh[y:y+h, x:x+w]
result = black[0:max_ht, 0:w]
result[0:h, 0:w] = crop

# create center padding and concatenate
pad_center_img = np.zeros((max_ht,padding), dtype=np.uint8)
result = cv2.hconcat((result, pad_center_img))

# Take second entry in sorted list and crop, pad and concatenate
item = cntr_list[1]
x = item[0]
y = item[1]
w = item[2]
h = item[3]
crop = thresh[y:y+h, x:x+w]
temp = black[0:max_ht, 0:w]
temp[0:h, 0:w] = crop
result = cv2.hconcat((result, temp))

# Pad all around as desired
result = cv2.copyMakeBorder(result, 25, 25, 25, 25, borderType=cv2.BORDER_CONSTANT, value=(0))

# write result to disk
cv2.imwrite("lungs_mask_cropped.jpg", result)

# display it
cv2.imshow("thresh", thresh)
cv2.imshow("result", result)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Result:

[image]